# Multiple GitLab accounts SSH

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I have multiple GitLab accounts and I am trying to set up SSH authentication. I have generated the key pairs and saved them in `~/.ssh/public/proj1[2]/id_rsa.pub` and `~/.ssh/private/proj1[2]/id_rsa` My `~/.ssh/config` looks like this

```
Host proj1
  HostName gitlab.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private/proj1/id_rsa

Host proj2
  HostName gitlab.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private/proj2/id_rsa
```

now when I try to clone a repository from proj1 like
`git clone git@proj1:user_and_stuff.git`
I get an error that I don't have sufficient privileges.
I have enabled the `-vv` flag in the ssh of git and first it correctly identifies the key

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for proj1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/private/proj1/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/private/proj1/id_rsa-cert type -1
```

but then a few lines later out of nowhere

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/private/proj2/id_rsa RSA SHA256:fp agent
debug1: Will attempt key: unrelated_key1 RSA SHA256:fp agent
debug1: Will attempt key: unrelated_key2 RSA SHA256:fp agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/user/.ssh/private/proj1/id_rsa  explicit
```

it offers the wrong key first and since proj2 is also a gitlab account it successfully authenticated. Which of course generates the permission error because it tries to clone proj1 when authenticated with the key of proj2.

Any advice ?
I'm using mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the mac ssh agent is not capable of using specific keys to specific servers. 
We solved it by removing all keys from the agent
`ssh-add -D`
and removing the line
`AddKeysToAgent yes`
from the `~/.ssh/config` entries to prevent the keys being added to the agent.